# GitHub API File Update : "Not Found"

Tags: api, file-upload, github, fileupdate

I am attempting to update a file in one of my repos via the API.

Here is my get of that file (works nicely):

```
curl -XGET 'https://git.fake.local/api/v3/repos/jsmith/repo_version/contents/version.html?ref=gh-pages'
{
  "name": "version.html",
  "path": "version.html",
  "sha": "b1b716105590454bfc4c0247f193a04088f39c7f",
  "size": 5,
  "url": "https://git.fake.local/api/v3/repos/jsmith/post_version/contents/version.html?ref=gh-pages",
  "html_url": "https://git.fake.local/jsmith/post_version/blob/gh-pages/version.html",
  "git_url": "https://git.fake.local/api/v3/repos/jsmith/post_version/git/blobs/b1b716105590454bfc4c0247f193a04088f39c7f",
  "type": "file",
  "content": "aW5pdAo=\n",
  "encoding": "base64",
  "_links": {
    ...
  }
}
```

Here is my attempt to update that file via PUT:

```
curl -XPUT 'https://git.fake.local/api/v3/repos/jsmith/repo_version/contents/version.html?ref=gh-pages' -d '{
   "message": "update from api",
   "committer": {
     "name": "Joe Smith",
     "email": "jsmith@fake.com"
   },
   "content": "bXkgdXBkYXRlZCBmaWxlIGNvbnRlbnRz",
   "sha": "b1b716105590454bfc4c0247f193a04088f39c7f"
 }'
```

RESULT:

```
{
  "message": "Not Found"
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay... I think I got it.

From the github doco:

> **Authentication**
>
> There are three ways to authenticate through GitHub API v3. Requests
>   that require authentication will return `404 Not Found`, instead
>   of `403 Forbidden`, in some places. This is to prevent the
>   accidental leakage of private repositories to unauthorized users.

I was expecting a 403 if Auth was a problem but they are throwing a 404, so basically I probably need to make sure I am auth'd correctly and all will be well.

SOLVED:
I created a personal oauth token (under settings/applications) and add to curl request in header and it all works great.

`curl -XPUT  -H "Authorization: token MYSECRETTOKEN"`

Comment: I can add to this (somewhat wryly) that it helps if you spell 'authorisation' the American way...

Comment: I can vouch for this. I'm using the API to update files and I was getting 404 "Not Found".  My token was valid but was missing some scopes. In particular I had to add the " workflow" scope to be able to write files.